# Replace sequence of the same letter with single one

Tags: python, string

I am trying to replace the number of letters with a single one, but seems to be either hard either I am totally block how this should be done
So example of input:

- > `aaaabbcddefff`

The output should be `abcdef`
Here is what I was able to do, but when I went to the last piece of the string I can't get it done. Tried different variants, but I am stucked. Can someone help me finish this code?

```
text = "aaaabbcddefff"

new_string = ""

count = 0

while text:

for i in range(len(text)):

    l = text[i]

    for n in range(len(text)):

        if text[n] == l:
            count += 1
            continue

        new_string += l
        text = text.replace(l, "", count)
        break

    count = 0
    break
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "can't get it done"?

Comment: Just use `"".join(sorted(list(set(list(text)))))`...

Comment: Also what should be the output if you have `aabbccddaa` as the input?

Comment: Like @ko3 's answer, you could use Numpy's `unique` function: `"".join(numpy.unique(list(text)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `re`:

```
import re

re.sub(r"(.)(?=\1+)", "", text)
```

Using zip:

```
"".join(x for x, y in zip(text, text[1:]) if x!= y) + text[-1]
```

Using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

"".join(map(itemgetter(0), groupby(text)))
```

Comment: Also thanks for this other view of the task. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Side note: You should consider building your string up in a list and then joining the list, because it is expensive to append to a string, since strings are immutable.

One way to do this is to check if every letter you look at is equal to the previous letter, and only append it to the new string if it is not equal:

```
def remove_repeated_letters(s):
    if not s: return ""

    ret = [s[0]] 
    for index, char in enumerate(s[1:], 1):
        if s[index-1] != char:
            ret.append(char)

    return "".join(ret)
```

Then, `remove_repeated_letters("aaaabbcddefff")` gives `'abcdef'`.
`remove_repeated_letters("aaaabbcddefffaaa")` gives `'abcdefa'`.

Alternatively, use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), which groups consecutive equal elements together, and join the keys of that operation

```
import itertools

def remove_repeated_letters(s):
    return "".join(key for key, group in itertools.groupby(s))
```

Comment: Thanks. That was what I need. I did not think that I need to convert the string into list.

Comment: @DanailLesev you don't need a list, but it makes your code more efficient. The key part of the logic is to loop over the string and compare each character with the previous character